# Angular Time validation does not appear to be working in 1.3?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-validation

I have a simple set of code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="test">
   {{time}}<br>
      <input ng-model="time" type="time" placeholder="HH:mm" min="08:00" max="17:00" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

It is available to execute from here: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/9824/
This JSFiddle is using 1.3.0.beta 17

If I change the Fiddle to the 1.3 release, it sees *every* time as invalid.

(If the time is valid, it appears above the data entry box.)

Any thoughts on what is wrong with this validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably is how input [type time](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btime%5D) validation is implemented in angular. So in your case your input exceeds `max` limit (during parser validation for max value) because of the date that you are providing. i.e `new Date()` which is the current date. When you have `max` value specified as `17:00` angular converts this to ISO date format for its validation (Which is weird for validating time), i.e it converts it as 
Epoch date i.e it would become `1970-01-01T17:00:00.00000Z` and it compares the time to see if it exceeds. You can test that out by providing max as valid ISO date-time format.

Example:-

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/xHcpyU9yfL3wfncCUmFn?p=preview)**

If you do not specify any date part, input type time's ng-model needs the exact date of the `Epoch` (i.e `1 January 1970`). It outputs as the specified time with date `1/1/1970`.

If you really use time and set value in DOM directly `elm.valueAsDate = new Date(2014, 1, 1, 7, 34);` the element's HTML5  property (`elm.validity`) returns valid as true, so this is definitely with angular implementation.

So in your case try setting the time as:-

Example:-

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var dt = new Date();
  $scope.time = new Date(1970,0,1,dt.getHours(),dt.getMinutes(),dt.getSeconds());
});
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/yiRPor?p=preview)**

Comment: Based on your comment "which is weird for validating time" ... does this appear to you as a bug that should be reported?

Comment: For example, I am building a class scheduler. The entered times need to be between 7 AM and 10 PM for the classes. I don't see a way to readily validate the entry of the time without hard-coding in the date as in your demo. Seems like time validation should be separate from a date?